# Prevent create controller every request .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

```
public class BankingAccountController : BaseController
{ 
     public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
     {
          //Get Data From Temp Table
     } 

     public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
     {
          //Post Correct data
     }

     public async Task<IActionResult> Put()
     {
          //Edit temp Data by User
     }
}
```

When first request send by user to controller index method fetch data from temp Table.

Then when user edit the temp data and click to post correct data , first index run and get data from temp table then post data.

So user edit is missed.

My question is here

How to Prevent to create controller every time ?

Comment: Try to think what happens if **two** users edit the data at the same time. First user displays the data, then the second displays the data. Then the first user POSTs his changes.

Comment: It is like that by design. You cannot really make the it stop creating an instance of the controller. Look at the above comment for why. If you want the data set to be same each time then you have to keep it in a data store (memory class injected via DI, database, static class, etc...)